# "One of the perpetrator’s faces" or "One of the perpetrators’ faces"?

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe, saxon-genitive

I'm a transcriber and this has been a debate.  An attorney says: "One of the perpetrators faces."  Would you use 's or s'?

Comment: There are two perpetrators but they only have a still photograph of one of their faces.  So they are saying, essentially, one of two people's faces.

Comment: I think the way you put it in that last sentence gives a clue to the answer... you didn't write "one of two person's faces" but "one of two people's faces" with the plural possessive noun "people's".  The phrase that you asked about likewise calls for a plural possessive noun, which would be spelled `perpetrators'`.

Comment: Attorneys are notoriously arrogant. They make language mistakes all the time. I know because I deal with their mistakes....:)

Comment: @Katie That's a good trick for questions about plurals and possessives together. "Children" is my go-to. It doesn't always help, in cases where the answer to the question is unclear even in the singular, but it often helps.

Comment: I have no idea who gave you a down vote, but this is a perfectly reasonable question to ask. (Other answers are correct, so I will not provide my own. However, it can also be rephrased in such a way that no apostrophe is needed: "The face belongs to one of the perpetrators.")

Comment: Agreed.  It's an odd sentence.  Attorneys commonly word things in a strange manner.  I agree with you, @GreenGrassoHolm

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly "one of the perpetrators' faces", that is, "one of the faces belonging to the perpetrators".

Exception: If you've got a perpetrator with more than one face, then it could be "one of the faces belonging to the perpetrator" = "one of the perpetrator's faces".

Comment: Thank you so much! I agree with you.  However, everyone in the office disagrees with me.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to write, "One of the perpetrators' faces."

**You add *'s* to the following:**

To the singular form of the word (even if it ends in -s).
To the plural forms that do not end in -s.
To the end of compound words.
To the last noun to show joint possession of an object.

---

You only add *'* to the end of plural nouns that end in -s.

As can be seen, "Perpetrators" is plural and ends in -s, therefore you must use s'. I hope this helps.